# Long running job termination in Databricks

Tags: timeout, databricks, jobs, job-scheduling, termination

We are trying to figure out how best to monitor long-running jobs automatically. Say, over X=3 hours. In Snowflake, users can put a resource governor that terminates these things. In EMR, users can monitor and alert. Is there a best practice or easy knob to turn to do this for Databricks jobs?

Answer (score 0):

In the advanced drop-down for a task, there is an option to set a timeout.

[image: Drop down screecshot]
[image: Another screenshot]

See the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/jobs.html#timeout) for more options and information.